# Format automatic short citation in footnote-dw / biblatex to italic

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex style footnote-dw but need all titles to be italic, as this is my way of emphasising them in the proper text as well. I managed to achieve this for all cases but for repeat citations, where only the title is given. Is there a way to set this cursive?

[image]

MWE (with possibly relevant stuff):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}


\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib} 
    @book{Kant1, 
        author={Manu Kant}, 
        title={Critique of Pure Treason}, 
        subtitle={Why are there no pink MandMs},
        address={Chocolvania}, 
        year=2017
    } 

    @book{Kant4, 
    author={Franz Kant}, 
title={Down with pink}, 
subtitle={A heteronormative misogynist manifesto},
address={Reesestown}, 
shorthand={Manifesto},
year=2008
}

        @book{Kant2, 
    author={Franz Kant}, 
    title={Ignore my Brother}, 
    subtitle={Hes an idiot},
    address={Reesestown}, 
    shorthand={Moron},
    year=2018
}   
\end{filecontents*}



\usepackage[style=footnote-dw,
backend=biber,
edbyidem=true,
nopublisher=true,
edsuper=true,
idembibformat=dash,
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand}{\emph{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\emph{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
The argument between the Brothers Kant\footnote{See \cite[123]{Kant1} and \cite[5]{Kant2}.} seems to boil\cite[43]{Kant1} down\cite[2]{Kant1} mostly to sugary treats.\cite[7]{Kant2} Mmmmmhmmm sugary treats.\footnote{Yet see also the sexist underpinnings in \cite{Kant1}, cf. \cite{Kant4}!} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short citations are typeset with the field format `citetitle`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

Note the use of `\mkbibemph` instead of `\emph`.

Comment: Thanks!! I hoped for something as simple as this - and duly noted and adapted the correct "emph".

Comment: Ah, now I also got the logic behind it, I think. I assumed that citetitle was only meant as a special citation and didn't expect it to be called in regular footnote \cites. Thanks again - learned something.

Comment: @PaulBurgh Yup. `citetitle` is the normal format for titles in citations. With `verbose`-like styles where the first citation is a full citation, the very first occurrence of a work does not use `citetitle`, instead it uses `title` as does the bibliography.